# Is there a real-world benchmark of Java vs C++?

Tags: java, c++, performance, benchmarking

Before I get to the question, please note what this question is NOT:

- Is Java slower (or faster) than C++?
- Why is Java slower (or faster) than C++?

This question doesn't solicit opinions, it solicits facts -- numbers.

Many benchmarks, like https://days2011.scala-lang.org/sites/days2011/files/ws3-1-Hundt.pdf or http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/ test something synthetic, like Mandelbrot, or at best a tiny part of a real program, like array sorting. Naturally, that won't produce representative numbers like benchmarking an entire app would.

So, is there a benchmark that uses a real, complete app like:

- a notes app or word processor
- a maps app like Google Maps
- an email client
- a web server

It has to be something you use everyday -- a complete app, and not a tiny portion of one, like binary trees or sorting arrays.

Any measurement of performance will do, whether latency or throughput. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt any large apps developed two versions, one written in Java, one in C++. Most just use whatever makes more sense for the particular task.

Comment: In order to be able to benchmark two real application is that they are developed using the same design and the same algorithms, which I doubt it is, but you could be the entrepreneur.

Comment: @RamonBoza That's precisely where the problem lies.  Different languages have different ways of expressing things, and a team of experienced C++ programmers, writing in C++, will often _not_ choose the same organization as a team of experienced Java programmers, writing in Java.

Comment: http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/benchmarks_all

Comment: >>won't produce representative numbers like benchmarking an entire app would<< Measuring an entire app will only produce measurements for that app -- no reason to think that they would be representative of other apps.

Comment: Fair enough, but it would still be more representative than Mandelbrot or array sorting. I'll settle for that.

Comment: Can I ask why this is put on hold? It's not opinion-based, but fact-based. What's the minimal understanding of this problem I'm told I lack?

Comment: @Kartick Vaddadi >it would still be more representative than Mandelbrot< No, that's just a bad assumption. "The performance of a benchmark, even if it is derived from a real program, may not help to predict the performance of similar programs that have different hot spots." If you want something representative of a particular usage you have to collect data about that usage and check -- http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/dont-jump-to-conclusions.php

Comment: Aren't you putting it in black and white terms here? It's not that something is or isn't representative of a real-world scenario, but what is MORE representative? I still think a notes app, or mail client, or web server, or Google Maps is more representative of my day to day usage than Mandelbrot or DNA sequencing. I'm not saying it's perfect -- one can't have a perfect benchmark. I'm only saying it's better.

Comment: @Kartick Vaddadi >>I'm only saying it's better.<< That's just your wild guess -- it might be worse ;) Until you collect data about that usage and check you simply don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no, and I'm tempted to say that it isn't
even possible, at least economically.  To do so, you'd have to
implement the same application twice, with two different teams,
in parallel at the same time.  And even then: how much of the
difference is due to the language, and how much to the relative
competence of the teams, etc.

In the end, you cannot compare the performance of "languages".
At best, you can compare the performance of language
implementations, when used by specific programmers for specific
tasks.  Which, in a certain sense, is all that interests you: 
you have to implement a specific application with the programmers you
have and the language implementations which are available to
you.  Even if there were a comparison such as you seek, it
wouldn't help you much, because you'll be implementing
a different application with a different group of programmers
(who likely have a different skill set than the programmers who
implemented the benchmark).  And while different languages do
have characteristics which make optimization more or less
difficult, on the whole, in larger applications (as
opposed to synthetic benchmarks), these tend to be outweighed by
large considerations, or offset by other characteristics which
also affect optimizing: the pointer semantics of C/C++ are
a bane to optimizers; on the other hand, optimizing Java will
require extensive boxing, which isn't trivial either.  (FWIW:
the easiest language to optimize is probably Fortran.  Not
because of anything intrinsic in the language, but because
researchers have been working on it the longest, and many of the
necessary optimization techniques have become mainstream.)

If you're really concerned, you'll have to have the programmers
available to you write their own benchmarks, based on patterns
in your application, and implemented by your programmers.

And finally: a lot of real apps, including things like a word
processor, an email client or a web server are IO bound; their
performance depends more on the speed of IO than anything else.
(For most of the large scale servers I've worked on, we didn't
even bother turning on the optimizer.  Despite the fact that
they were time critical; the CPU time just didn't have an
impact.)

Comment: To your last comment: I think on word processors and email clients, the most time is spent idling while waiting for the user to do something, so it's kind of hard to put good "throughput" numbers on these kind of apps. OK, response time to user input can be measured, but that's more or less the only really good number you can get. Also, that's the only number the user will be interested in in his email client. "If I press send, I expect the program to return really quick".

Comment: @arne Agreed.  More to the point, here, however: when I press send, the limiting factor will be the communications time with the email server, not CPU time.  It's the sort of program that you probably wouldn't even bother optimizing.

Comment: It depends. One could run a benchmark that measures how long it takes to sync all your email, like 10GB, when you're setting up the email client for the first time. Run a fast local server (lots of cores and RAM), connected by gigabit ethernet to the client machine. Equip both machines with SSDs (or, heck, RAMdisks) to get I/O out of the way.

Comment: Regarding the comment that we can compare only language implementations, not languages, sure, we could compare Sun's Java 7 VM with Clang/LLVM. Or with GCC. I'd be happy either way. Regarding the comment that we can compare performance for specific tasks, agreed, but I'll take an email client or web server benchmark as being more representative than Mandelbrot.

Comment: Regarding the comment about programmer proficiency, we could just use someone proficient with both C++ and Java, and have the same person / team build both versions. There's no shortage of such people. I consider myself one, for example. I'm not good at Python or C# or Rails, but I consider myself well-equipped to compare Java and C++. And, yes, people implementing a real app would be different from people implementing a benchmark, but that's always the case for benchmarks -- it doesn't mean we shouldn't do benchmarks :) We can never have a perfect benchmark, but we can have a useful one.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi Even with SSDs or RAMdisks, a significant part of an email server will be spent in IO.  It's a typical example of the type of application which does almost nothing but IO---you could probably implement in Python, and still hardly notice the difference.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi Of course, it's possible to create useful benchmarks.  My point is only that _you_ have to create them, since to be useful, they will depend on your application, your way of working, and your programmers.  (The Mandelbrot is very representative of a certain class of applications---it's certainly closer to what I'm doing now that an email client would be.  An email client is more representative of applications which are IO bound.)

Comment: @KartickVaddadi Concerning the Oracle JVM vs. g++ or Clang: for IO bound applications like an email client, the real difference would be Windows vs. Linux vs. Solaris, since most of the time will be spent in the OS anyway

Answer (score -7):

Java is slower than C++ and it can't be other way.
The reason of this is C++ compiles in native OS binary code that is understandable by OS. And Java code compiles to binary .class files which are executed by JVM. One more layer in comparison with C++. So, it's slower.

Comment: On the other hand, the Java virtual machine can dynamically reorganize the program execution based on runtime feedback, while a C++ compiler is forced to choose the least evil at compile time. Depending on what you're doing the dynamic approach can be advantageous. And of course individual bits of code are nowadays compiled to machine code in Java just as well.

Comment: Except when it isn't.  In practice, it's easy to write a benchmark in which Java is faster, just as it's easy to write a benchmark in which C++ is faster.  And of course, the performance of both will depend on the implementation, and the optimizations it does.

Comment: This answer was correct 10 years ago.  It's not as simple as that now.

Comment: Also, note that the question is **NOT** about java theoretical performance vs c++, it's about benchmark recommendations

Comment: @KerrekSB Also, because Java compiles for a specific environment, when the program is loaded, it can tune its optimization for precisely that hardware.  You can generally do this for C++ as well, _if_ the application is only going to run on one machine, but typically, the C++ optimizer will make some compromises in order to obtain good performance on many different machines.

Comment: @StuPointerException The answer wasn't even correct 10 years ago.  Some time between 15 and 20 years ago, maybe.

Comment: @JamesKanze, may be there can be an example which is executed in JVM faster than in native OS. But in generally I don't think that native C++ binary file execution is slower then .class in JVM.

Comment: There exist Java processors that can run bytecode without a JVM. These are not even new -- I heard about pretty sophisticated ones during university ten years ago.

Comment: @arne, right - Azul for example came out with a JVM that can do HW level TM (transactional-memory), that would be a winner for data bases and any heavily lock-based program.

Comment: @Leeor: I was thinking more along the lines of embedded devices, but hey, another very good example.

Comment: @omickron What you think is irrelevant.  The relative performances depend on the implementation, and there are clearly real world cases where the Oracle Java implementation will outperform native C++.  (One of the best compiler specialists I know tells me that there's no way a statically compiled program can beat a JIT compiler in real world problems.  I think he's exaggerating, but there's certainly some truth in it.)

Comment: @arne Do you mean that the machine code was Java byte code?

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, although the processors were for embedded systems like I stated in response to Leeor. My point only was that this "second abstraction layer" that OP mentioned need not necessarily be there at all.

Comment: @arne It's not there in most JVM either.  Typically, the JVM will compile the byte code to machine code before executing it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I believe that used to be different a decade or two ago, like you mentioned before.

Comment: Sorry, @omickron, I explicitly said that that's not the question. It's not whether and why Java is slower (or faster). It's: is there a real app used as a benchmark?

Comment: Yes, @KartickVaddadi, you're right. I didn't understand the question correctly